# MPMediaPickerController | Access iPod library's audio files (and no videos)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, mpmediapickercontroller

I am working on a music player app, in which user can create custom playlists. So I want to show a MPMediaPickerController populated with iPod's library audios. The issue am facing is that MPMediaPickerController also shows music videos along with the audio items.

Am initializing the picker view with mediaTypes MPMediaTypesAnyAudio as

```
MPMediaPickerController* picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
```

Same is the issue with MPMediaQuery

```
[MPMediaQuery songsQuery]
```

also returns videos along with the audio items. 
It seems that accessing videos has been made available on launch of iOS 5. For iOS < 5, MPMediaPickerController would only show audios. Is there any way I can filter out videos and only audio files are displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: very strange, because I dont see any videos even when I try to force it with MPMediaTypeAny or MPMediaTypeAnyVideo

Comment: You don't see any videos probably because you don't have any music videos. The videos you have in your library are probably movies/Tv shows. They don't appear in the mediaPicker, only music videos does. You can give it a try, select the video in iTunes, right click and then get info, you can then change the video type. Change it to music video, sync again and the video should appear in the picker view.